# Container div background behind child divs

Tags: html, background

On this page: http://www.chronicallyhappy.nl/

I added a "footer-wrap" div to the "footer" div (in the footer.php of the Wordpress theme). Then in CSS I added a background image to the "footer-wrap" div. The problem: it keeps showing below the background color for the "footer" div. I tried adding "position:relative" and "z-index" values for both divs, but no luck.

This is the result I want to achieve: http://nl.tinypic.com/r/2hhdcwn/8

What am I doing wrong?

My CSS:

```
.footer-wrap {
    padding-top: 19px;
    background: url("../style/img/golfjes.png") repeat-x top left;
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5;
}

.footer { 
    width: 100%; 
    padding: 65px 0 31px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #C71A4E;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Thank you so much!
Stefaan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should put the ribbon in the footer, not wrapping it around, and position it top minus a few pixels. As you have the footer within the wrap, and it has a background color, it overlaps with its bg.

so what you need is:

```
 <footer div with background color>
     <ribbon div positioned a bit top minus>
     </ribbon div>
       <footer content>
       </footer content>
 </footer div>
```